# brew upgrade MacOs 11.3.1 error message curl: (7) Failed to connect to ghcr.io port 443: Bad file descriptor

Tags: terminal, homebrew, apple-m1

[image]

Hi all I'm trying to update packages and encountered such an error message, anyone with similar experience managed to solve it, or what could be causing the error

MacOs 11.3.1
M1 model not intel.
brew installation is for M1 arm not running rosetta

Answer (score 0):

`https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core` is the `HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN`, where all the prebuilt binary releases (bottles) are cached.

One of the reason is that the cached prebuilt is deleted, which indicated the `homebrew-core` repo is outdated.

Do a `brew update` and have a try againg.